# Why is my object being disposed?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

I'm trying to access SQL server using LINQ with c# in asp.net framework.
I'm writing a simple log-in form on a webpage. The following is my c# code to check if it is in the database.

```
public int getUserId(string un, string pw)
    {
        IEnumerable<int> query;
        using (var context = new IngredientsLinqDataContext())
        {
            query = from c in context.USERs
                        where c.Username == un && c.Password == pw
                        select c.UserID;
        }
        if(query.Count() >= 1)
        {
            return query.Min();//a very serious kludge. Need to fix this
        }
        else { return -1; }

    }
}
```

An object-disposed-exception is thrown when checking if the count of the query is greater than or equal to one. I had thought that, since query gets declared outside of the curly braces, this shouldn't be an issue of scope. 
Additionally, what is a good way to fix the kludge? It should only be returning a single int, not a list of ints. How can I treat it that way? Thanks!

Comment: you can select any of the answers and do wha they say... OR you could just extend your `using` block and close it after your `Count()` call. it'll do.

Comment: Why are you using `.Count() >= 1`? Why don't you just use `.Any()` so that it doesn't have to traverse the entire list counting just to see if there's at least one item.

Comment: A side note (but an important one). You should not, in this day and age, be storing passwords as plain text in a database. Even if this is just a "toy" example, *practicing good security discipline is a good idea*.

Comment: Also, I'd strongly suggest just using `Single()` over `Count` and `Min` - you expect a single result so ask for one. And if it produces multiple results or no results, it throws an exception, which is how you should be dealing with these errors, rather than going back to C-style "passing magic values back to indicate an error".

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
query = from c in context.USERs
        where c.Username == un && c.Password == pw
        select c.UserID;
```

to

```
query = (from c in context.USERs
        where c.Username == un && c.Password == pw
        select c.UserID).ToList();
```

LINQ is using deferred execution, so you query is not evaluated immediately, but it is evaluated only at `query.Count()`. The `context` at that moment is already disposed. That's why you receive error.

Comment: @JudahSchwartz beware that .`ToList();` will bring all the data matches the condition. if your only interested in count, do `query.Count()`;

Answer (score 1):

`context` is disposed because you are trying to retrieve the data from database out of the `context` using block;

```
    using (var context = new IngredientsLinqDataContext())
    {
        query = from c in context.USERs
            where c.Username == un && c.Password == pw
            select c.UserID;
        if (query.Count() >= 1)
        {
            return query.Min();//a very serious kludge. Need to fix this
        }
        else { return -1; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to be aware that a Linq query can be`AsEnumerable` or `AsQueryable`.

If your query is `AsEnumerable` it holds all information needed to access the elements in your query: You can ask for the first element in your sequence (if there is one), and once you've got an element you can ask for the next one (if there is one). If your query uses other functions in your process, it has all information to access these other functions. In short: `AsEnumerable` is processed in local memory.

If your query is `AsQueryable` it holds an `Expression` and a `Provider`. The `Provider` knows which process is designated to process the `Expression`. It knows which language this process uses. It is the task of the `Provider` to convert the `Expression` into the language of the destination processor and to send it to this processor.

For Entity Framework this is usually a database like SQL or MySQL, but it could also be a spreadsheet or a CSV file. The nice thing about a `DbContext` is that you don't need to know which language it uses to communicate with the other process. You could use the same IDbSet classes to communicate with a completely different process.

So an `IQueryable` does not hold the information to enumerate over the elements in the query. It only knows how to translate it into the language of the designated process and who to ask to execute this query.

The translation and execution is not done until you ask for elements. This means that you have to keep the providing object that your query uses alive until you don't need any more results from this providing object anymore.

Executing the query is done whenever you ask for a function that doesn't use  *deferred execution* (as is described in the remarks section of every linq function). These are functions like ToList(), FirstOrDefault(), Single(), Count(), etc.

Functions like `Where`, `Select`, `GroupBy` and others that use deferred execution only change the `Expression`.

> **Conclusion**
>   Make sure you've fetched all data that you need from your provider before
>   you Dispose() it

Answer (score 0):

May be this will fix your issue.

```
public int getUserId(string un, string pw)
    {
        int query;
        using (var context = new IngredientsLinqDataContext())
        {
            --change here
            query = (from c in context.USERs
                        where c.Username == un && c.Password == pw
                        select c.UserID).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        if(query != 0)       --change here
        {
            return query;//a very serious kludge. Need to fix this
        }
        else { return -1; }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your use of `query` in this construct instructs `LINQ` to wait until the object is accessed before executing the actual query against the database. In this case `query` is accessed outside your `using` block, so that's why you're getting the error.

Try this:

```
result = (from c in context.USERs
          where c.Username == un && c.Password == pw
          select c.UserID).Min();
```

Comment: I see an exception in this code's future. [Like this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5k9wvq) for example.

Comment: @john — I do believe you're clairvoyant ;-) Thanks for the correction, I appreciate it.